# CIFS(Samba) + ACL = not working

Tags: linux, samba, server-message-block, access-control-list, cifs

I have two servers with Debian 5.0.

server1:
samba 2:3.2.5-4lenny9
smbfs 2:3.2.5-4lenny9

smb.conf:

```
[test]
   comment = test
   path = /var/www/_test/
   browseable = no
   only guest = yes
   writable = yes
   printable = no
   create mask = 0644
   directory mask = 0755

server1:~# mount | grep sda3
/dev/sda3 on /var/www type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)

# getfacl /var/www/_test/
# file: var/www/_test/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rw-
default:user:testuser:rw-
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

server2:

samba-common 2:3.2.5-4lenny9
smbfs        2:3.2.5-4lenny9

```
server2:~# mount.cifs  //server1/test /media/smb/test -o rw,user_xattr,acl
server2:~# mount | grep test
//server1/test on /media/smb/test type cifs (rw,mand)
server2:~# getfacl /media/smb/test/
# file: media/smb/test/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rw-
default:user:testuser:rw-
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

And there is the problem:

```
server2:~# su - testuser
(reverse-i-search)`touch': touch 123
testuser@server2:~$ touch /media/smb/
testuser@server2:~$ touch /media/smb/test/123
touch: cannot touch `/media/smb/test/123': Permission denied
```

Whats wrong?!

Answer (score 3):

You need execute permissions on the folder as well. Touch does one of two things:

1. If the file specified exists, updates the timestamp
2. If the file specified does not exist, create a new file

To know if /media/smb/test/123 exists, touch needs to list directory contents of the smb folder, which requires execute permission.